# How to fix this error? assert names_requests == names_selenium AssertionError

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Функція для збору даних з використанням requests та BeautifulSoup
def scrape_with_requests(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    plugin_names = []
    plugin_authors = []
    plugin_ratings = []
    # Приклад використання з BeautifulSoup
    elements = soup.select('.plugin_support_reps-tacoverdo a')
    blocks = soup.find_all('div', class_='plugin-card')
    for block in blocks:
        name = block.find('h3', class_='entry-title').text.strip()
        author = block.find('span', class_='plugin-author').text.strip()
        rating = block.find('span', class_='plugin-rating').text.strip()

        plugin_names.append(name)
        plugin_authors.append(author)
        plugin_ratings.append(rating)

    return plugin_names, plugin_authors, plugin_ratings

# Функція для збору даних з використанням selenium
def scrape_with_selenium(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Потрібно встановити Chrome WebDriver
    driver.get(url)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    while True:
        try:
            show_more_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'plugins-section-more')))
            show_more_button.click()
            time.sleep(5)  # Затримка у 2 секунди для завантаження додаткових даних
        except:
            break
    time.sleep(5)
    plugin_names = []
    plugin_authors = []
    plugin_ratings = []

    blocks = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'plugin-card')
    for block in blocks:
        name = block.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry-title').text.strip()
        author = block.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'plugin-author').text.strip()
        rating = block.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'plugin-rating').text.strip()

        plugin_names.append(name)
        plugin_authors.append(author)
        plugin_ratings.append(rating)

    driver.quit()

    return plugin_names, plugin_authors, plugin_ratings

# Посилання на сторінку з плагінами
url = 'https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/browse/blocks/'

# Збирання даних з використанням requests та BeautifulSoup
names_requests, authors_requests, ratings_requests = scrape_with_requests(url)

# Збирання даних з використанням selenium
names_selenium, authors_selenium, ratings_selenium = scrape_with_selenium(url)
if names_requests == names_selenium:
    print("Names match!")
else:
    print("Names do not match!")

if authors_requests == authors_selenium:
    print("Authors match!")
else:
    print("Authors do not match!")

if ratings_requests == ratings_selenium:
    print("Ratings match!")
else:
    print("Ratings do not match!")
# Перевірка, що дані, зібрані обома методами, співпадають
assert names_requests == names_selenium
assert authors_requests == authors_selenium
assert ratings_requests == ratings_selenium

# Створення DataFrame
data = {
    'Plugin Name': names_requests,
    'Author': authors_requests,
    'Rating': ratings_requests
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Збереження у файл Excel
df.to_excel('wordpress_plugins.xlsx', index=False)

print("Дані успішно зібрано та збережено у файлі 'wordpress_plugins.xlsx'")
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. Is there a way for you to provide an English translation? While this group spans the globe, it is a forum that is mainly English based. This will get you more help!